# Frequent BSoD Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod, irq

For the past week I have been getting BSoD on my Windows 7 home built PC.  It's an old computer, I built it back in 2006 or 2007.  I hadn't had trouble with it until now.

I have BlueScreenView to look at the dump files.  I get some similarities but they are different each time.

Bug Check Strings I get:

- IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION

Mostly I get the IRQL or DRIVER ones.

As for the Driver that causes each one, thats also different each time too.  Although I do see ntoskrnl.exe pop up more often than anything else.  Other ones I have seen:
Wdff01000.sys
NETIO.SYS
hal.dll

I have run System File Checker in the command line, no problems detected.  I have also specifically checked ntoskrnl.exe.

I have reinstalled my GPU driver.

I have used compressed air to clean out all the dust, though it really wasn't so bad.  I do it about once a year I think.

Not sure what else to try.

Specs:

- Win 7 pro 64-bit
- Gigabyte Mobo: GA-EP45-UD3R v1.1
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q8200 @ 2.33Ghz
- 4 gigs of ddr2 ram
- NVidia GeForce 9600 GT

If you need anything else, please let me know.  I in the middle of studying for CompTIA's A+ cert, so this is kind of annoying that I can't figure it out on my own.  Although I'm wondering if maybe a piece of hardware is going bad.

Thanks

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Answer (score 2):

This sounds suspiciously like a Power supply problem and/or other hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a consistent way to repro the BSOD. Perhaps by running a benchmark or memory stress test.

Once that happens, you can start trying to figure out what the culprit is.

If your memory is in multiple DIMMS, you should probably try one stick at a time to rule out a bad memory stick. If not, assuming you have spare parts, try a different memory DIMM. Always make sure there is a DIMM in mem slot 0 (the one nearest to the CPU socket)

After that move on to a different video card, cpu, hard drive, mobo... (If memory is not it, it will get difficult to sort out)

In my experience, when the BSOD is all over the place, it's usually memory gone bad. However, I've never seen a memory stick turn bad when left alone. I've gotten bad memory but have never had good memory go bad.